# php memory_get_usage on windows

Tags: php

Is there any way to get `memory_get_usage()` and `memory_get_peak_usage()` to work on windows ? (php version 5.2) I get an *undefined function* fatal error.

Comment: Check this comment http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.memory-get-usage.php#87092

Comment: i don't have access to httpd.conf of Apache

Comment: There is a detailed blog post about mem http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/#N1018B and a neat function for windows.

Comment: There is a bug filed in for windows system about this function here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34115

Comment: [ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/#N1018B](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/#N1018B) did the trick (and great explanation!) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [explanation at ibm.com about PHP and memory](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/#N1018B). There is also an explanation how to receive the memory information with a shell command on windows:

```
$output = array();
exec('tasklist /FI "PID eq '.getmypid().'" /FO LIST', $output);
echo preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $output[5] ) * 1024;
```

Comment: Yes I read that but implemented with the method described in the [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/#N1018B) you posted as comment. Thanks.

Comment: I added it as full answer, so you can accept this answer and we both will receive those great stackoverflow.com points ;)